# Passing Shell Commands from a C# Program, Quotation Marks Disappearing

Tags: c#, shell, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am trying to execute a shell command on my Pi running on Raspbian but the quotation marks seem to disappear.

```
string quote = "\"";
string argument = "-vf" + " -hf" + " -o" + @" /home/pi/Desktop/camera/" + "$(date +" + quote + "%d%m%Y_%H%M-%S" + quote + ").jpg";
Process.Start("/usr/bin/raspistill", argument);
```

Here is the script I'm trying to execute:

```
sudo raspistill -vf -hf -o /home/pi/Desktop/camera/$(date +"%d%m%Y_%H%M-%S").jpg
```

And here is the error I'm getting:

> Invalid command line option (+%d%m%Y_%H%M-%S).jpg)

As you can see, the quotation marks seem to have disappeared.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not really an answer as I can't test, but try to double escape the quotes... "\\\""

Comment: @SparK Well the quotation marks are there now, still not working though: "Invalid command line option (+"%d%m%Y_%H%M-%S").jpg)"

Comment: @Spark you have the right of it, I posted below with a link to a working DotNetFiddle

Comment: To me it doesn't look like the double quotes are the problem. The date command should work without quoting the +%d%m... args. I think the problem is around the $( ) construct not actually executing the date so that the formatstring will appear as extra command line option after the filename /home/pi/Desktop/camera/date . But I'm no c# expert so I may have misunderstood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not directly possible like this - $( )  is a shell expression and you do not invoke a shell but just only the raspistill command. There seems to be not "quoting" problems that I see (see comments)

**One way:**
Format the date string inside C# (I'm no expert but should be possible) and pass that formatted string directly

```
 ... +" -o" + " /home/pi/Desktop/camera/" + formateddate + ".jpg";
```

**Other way:**
Try to invoke /bin/sh and pass

```
"-c " + quote + "/usr/bin/raspistill " + argument + quote
```

as parameters:

```
string quote = "\"";
string argument = "-vf" + " -hf" + " -o" + 
" /home/pi/Desktop/camera/$(date +%d%m%Y_%H%M-%S).jpg";
Process.Start("/bin/sh", "-c " + quote + 
"/usr/bin/raspistill " +argument + quote);
```

However, I'm no C# expert and the way to pass it to ProcessStart may have to be fiddled around with. Also not sure where to place the sudo.

Would you try and let uns know?

Comment: I tried directly the second method and it worked perfectly. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

try replacing 
"$(date +" + quote + "%d%m%Y_%H%M-%S" + quote + ")

with: @"$(date+""%d%m%Y_%H%M-%S"")"

To escape the double quote character: "

You actually have to double double quotes like so: ""

[Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rGstHm) is the DotNetFiddle I used to test this

Comment: Now it says "Filename contains % characters, but not %d or %% - sorry, will fail Invalid command line option (/home/pi/Desktop/camera/$(date+%d%m%Y_%H%M-%S))".

Comment: @Pseudonym, it's funny how you misspelled "Dot**Not**Fiddle" haha

Comment: @JTSKhy that sounds like a problem with your command, can you elaborate a little bit more about what you're trying to do vs the error you're getting?